# Can't add more than one attachment to Contact Form 7

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

I am using Contact Form 7 on our website for people to book an event. Once they booked they will receive an ICS file and a ticket in PDF format. I'm using the `wpcf7_before_send_mail` hook to alter the email that gets sent to the user once they booked.

Everything works fine, I can add an attachment and it works, but as soon as I add more than one attachment it doesn't work.

I also confirmed, no errors in my code.

**Here's my code:**

```
add_attachments_before_send($WPCF7_ContactForm)  
{
     $wpcf       = WPCF7_ContactForm::get_current(); 
     $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

     if ($submission)
     {
         // This generates the ICS file and returns as a file path
         $ics    = generateICS( $pID, $dts, $dte, $venue );
         // This generates the event ticket file and also returns as a file path
         $ticket = generate_event_ticket( $pID, $dts, $venue, $name );

         $mail = $wpcf->prop('mail_2');

         if ($ics)
         {
            $mail['attachments'][] = $ics;
         }
         if ($ticket)
         {
            $mail['attachments'][] = $ticket;
         }

         $wpcf->set_properties(array(
            'mail_2' => $mail
         ));

         return $wpcf;
     }
}
add_action("wpcf7_before_send_mail", "add_attachments_before_send");
```

I have also tried replacing this `$mail['attachments'][] = $ics;` with `$mail['attachments'] .= $ics;` to use it as a string but also didn't work.

Comment: What do you see when it doesn't work? Are there any errors in the server or PHP's error log, or anything if you have WP_DEBUG enabled? At first glance there isn't really anything CF7-specific in their mail code, though: the attachments array just gets passed through to wp_mail.

Comment: @Rup I only get the email with no attachments. I just picked up an error: `explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in .../wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/mail.php on line 168`, so Im assuming it expects a string and also a new line (according to line 168) (`foreach ( explode( "\n", $template ) as $line )`)

Comment: Just did a test by adding a new line (\n) before adding the second attachment, and it worked! Thanx @Rup for pushing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured it out, kind of a stupid mistake. `$mail['attachments']` expects a string not an array. When adding multiple attachments each file needs to have a new line after it e.g. `\n`

For reference see the Contact Form 7 **mail.php** file located in the includes folder:
https://github.com/wp-plugins/contact-form-7/blob/master/includes/mail.php#L113